# Ion-router-outlet causing issues with already existing router-outlet in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In my app, in manager.component.html, I have the following, which has a router-outlet, and my app works wonderfully:

```
<div
  class="cu-manager2__router-outlet"
  [class.manager-space-bar]="!(hideSpacebar$ | async)"
>
  <cu2-spaces-bar
  ></cu2-spaces-bar>
  <router-outlet [hidden]="!(project$ | async)"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I decided to add a ion-menu as a slider:

```
<ion-menu 
  side="start" 
  menuId="sliding-menu" 
  class="slider-drawer" 
  type="overlay"
  (ionWillOpen)="menuOpened()"
  (ionDidOpen)="menuOpened()"
  (ionDidClose)="menuClosed()"
  >

    <ion-slides #ionSlider 
      pager="true" 
      class="ion-slides-container" 
      (ionSlideDidChange)="sliderDidChange()"
    >
      <ion-slide class="ion-slides-spaces-container">
        <div class="spaces-inner-container">
        </div>
      </ion-slide>
         
      <ion-slide class="ion-slides-folders-container">
          <div class = "folders-inner-container">
          </div>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides> 
</ion-menu>
<ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
```

This seems to work, 90% of the time.  Sometimes on initialization, there will be a routing problem and cause what was supposed to be shown with `<router-outlet>` to not be shown.

I discovered when I comment out `<ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>`, `router-outlet` works as expected.  It seems as if you can't have router-outlet and ion-router-outlet simultaneously.

What is the best solution to having both ion-router-outlet (needed for ion-menu) AND router-outlet in the same component?  is there a way to use `ion-menu` without `ion-router-outlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out you dont need ion-router-outlet

replace this:

`<ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>`

with the following (whatever your container you want to add the menu to):

`<div main class="main-container-padding"></div>`

All you have to do is add the `main` tag.